# do sequentially-consistent atomic loads (load-load pair) form an inter-thread synchronisation point?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

I am trying to understand what does sequentially-consistent ordering mean for loads. Consider this artificial example:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <cassert>

static std::atomic<bool> preStop {false};
static std::atomic<bool> stop {false};
static std::atomic<int> counter{0};

void waiter() {
    preStop.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    while (counter.load() > 0);
    stop.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

void performer() {
    while (true) {
        counter.fetch_add(1);
        const bool visiblePreStop = preStop.load();
        if (stop.load()) {
            assert(visiblePreStop);
            return;
        }
        counter.fetch_sub(1);
        std::this_thread::yield();
    }
}

int main() {
    std::thread performerThread(performer);
    std::thread waiterThread(waiter);
    waiterThread.join();
    performerThread.join();
}
```

Can `assert` fail? Or 
does `counter.fetch_add()` synchronise with `counter.load()`?

It is my understanding that had operations on `counter` have `std::memory_order_relaxed` or `std::memory_order_acq_rel`, the load-load pair would not create a synchronisation point. Does `std::memory_order_seq_cst` make any difference for load-load pairs?

Comment: The `assert` cannot fire since `stop` synchronizes access to `preStop`

Comment: You're right. I've edited the example to (hopefully) avoid that.

Comment: You haven't, you need relaxed atomics on everything except that you want to understand.

Comment: I don't fully see it (perhaps it's a part of an answer about how `seq_cst` works). I've modified the `stop.store()` to be relaxed, but I left all loads and all `counter` access to be sequential since it's a part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The assert can fail.  The sequential consistency of `counter.load()` implies that it is acquire, but that does not prevent the relaxed `preStop.store(true)` from being reordered after it.  Then `preStop.store(true)` may also be reordered after `stop.store(true)`.  If we have a weakly ordered machine with a store buffer, then nothing in `waiter()` ever drains the store buffer, so `preStop.store()` may languish there for an arbitrarily long time.

If so, then it is entirely possible that the code does something like

```
waiter
======
preStop.store(true, relaxed); // suppose not globally visible for a while
while (counter.load() > 0);   // terminates immediately
stop.store(true, relaxed);    // suppose globally visible right away  

performer
=========
counter.fetch_add(1);
preStop.load(); // == false
stop.load(); // == true
```

I don't quite understand the rest of the question, though.  Synchronization is established by a release store and an acquire load that reads the stored value (or another value later in the release sequence); when this occurs, it proves that the store happened before the load.  Two loads cannot synchronize with each other, not even if they are sequentially consistent.

But `counter.fetch_add(1)` is a read-modify-write; it consists of a load and a store.  Since it is `seq_cst`, the load is acquire and the store is release.  And `counter.load()` is likewise acquire, so if it returns 1, it does synchronize with `counter.fetch_add(1)`, proving that `counter.fetch_add(1)` happens before `counter.load()`.

But that doesn't really help.  The problem is that `waiter` doesn't do any release stores at all, so nothing in `performer` can synchronize with it.  Therefore neither of the relaxed stores in `waiter` can be proved to happen before the corresponding loads in `performer`, and so we cannot be assured that either load will return `true`.  In particular it is quite possible that `preStop.load()` returns `false` and `stop.load()` returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem where you're reading two *different* atomic variables but expect their state to be inter-dependent. This is similar, but not the same, as [Time-of-check to time-of-use bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use).

Here's a valid interleaving where the assert fires:

1. PerformerThread (PT) created
2. WaiterThread (WT) created
3. PT executes the following:

```
    while (true) {
        counter.fetch_add(1);
        const bool visiblePreStop = preStop.load();
```

4. PT sees that `visiblePreStop` is `false`
5. PT is suspended
6. WT executes the following:

```
    preStop.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    while (counter.load() > 0);
    stop.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

6. WT is suspended
7. PT executes the following:

```
        if (stop.load()) {
```

8. PT sees that `stop` is `true`
9. PT hits the assert because `visiblePreStop` is false and `stop` is `true

Comment: In step 3, `counter` was incremented to 1.  So in step 6, the `while (counter.load() > 0);` loop will not terminate and `stop.store(true)` will not execute.

Comment: In fact, I'm pretty sure interleaving alone cannot break this program, since if the `relaxed` accesses were upgraded to `seq_cst` the assert could not fire.  In order for `preStop.load()` to return `false`, it must precede `preStop.store(true)`.  But then it follows that `counter.fetch_add(1)` precedes `counter.load()` and so the spin loop will prevent `stop.store(true)` from occurring until after `counter.fetch_sub(1)`, which in particular is after `stop.load()`.  So if `preStop.load()` returns `false` then `stop.load()` returns `false` as well.